# How can I make reCAPTCHA a required field in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, recaptcha

I use "react-google-recaptcha" component and "material-ui" in my source.
Is there a way to make recaptcha required like other fields in material-ui forms?
like this field:

```
               <Field
                    name="description"
                    component={RenderTextField}
                    label={t('Description')}
                    placeholder={t('Description')}
                    multiLine={true}
                    rows={2}
                    required
                    InputProps={{
                        classes: {
                            input: classes.directionRevers
                        }
                    }}
                />

                <ReCAPTCHA
                    ref={recaptchaRef}
                    sitekey="6LcB-ysUAAAAAE_uDz0N0IiwjdwFGbqUTfcFi_Ey"
                    onChange={onChange}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new state recaptchaValid in your form and a text label to display required message.

Set recaptcchaValid state in onChange call back and on form submit check if recapchavalid state is invalid show the text message.

I hope this will help.